# I don't understand these lines of code from Object.assign() MDN documentation

Tags: javascript, object, methods

```
const obj1 = { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } };
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
console.log(obj2); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } }

obj1.a = 1;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } }

obj2.a = 2;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 2, b: { c: 0 } }

obj2.b.c = 3;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 2, b: { c: 3 } }
```

I was reading in the MDN documentation about Object.assign() method , then some lines of code stopped me (specifically starting from obj2.b.c = 3) . I don't understand how changing the c value in obj2 affected obj1 . Even though the values of the two (a) properties changed individually in each object before, and none of the two values affected the other . What do I not understand about the nested Object (b) ?

I would be thankful for any answers or references for articles that explains the problem and the solution deeply

Comment: "What do I not understand about the nested Object (b) " - what does that mean? How should we know what you don't understand? Do you have any **specific** question about this code?

Comment: You don’t understand that it’s the same object—assign is shallow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone

Comment: How did changing a property value in the nested object (b) affect both obj1 and obj2 and on changing the property (a) value in both obj1 and obj2 didn't affect each other ? (property a in obj1 is 1 and property a in obj2 is 2, while on updating the value of property c in one object , it's value also changed in the other one).

Comment: Object.assign does not make a copy of nested objects. obj1.b points to an object in memory, and ojb2.b points to the *same* object in memory. If you mutate the object, that change is visible no matter which way you access it

Comment: Consider using the browser API [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may read in [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone) page:

> For deep cloning, we need to use alternatives, because Object.assign()
> copies property values.
>
> If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies the
> reference value.

For more, read about [**Deep copy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) and [**Shallow copy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy).

---

In your example:

```
const obj1 = { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } };
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
```

`obj2` has a shallow copy of `obj1`, which means it has a copy of the values that are in the first level (`a`) and a reference to the object that's in `b`.

If you change `obj2.a`, you would change the value in the copy.

But when you do `obj2.b` you are using the reference of the object in `obj1` that had `{c: 0}`.

That's why when you change `obj2.b` you are referring to that same object (`c`) which was referred in `obj1`. They both point to the same memory address.

---

If you want to do a deep copy you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(OBJ))` which basically will create a string from your object, then it passes it to `JSON.stringif` which will return a new object (with new references).

You may also have a look at: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

**Object.assign** does not create a new object entirely. Instead it just creates a new reference to same memory location which is known as shallow copy. So that's why even if we are changing obj2 it changes obj1 as they are all pointing to same memory location.

If a new object had been created it would be known as deep copy.
Go through this article to read more about it.
https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

There's a browser API called [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) which may be what you're looking for:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } };
const obj2 = structuredClone(obj1);
console.log(obj2); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } }

obj1.a = 1;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0 } }

obj2.a = 2;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 2, b: { c: 0 } }

obj2.b.c = 3;
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: { c: 0 } }
console.log(obj2); // { a: 2, b: { c: 3 } }
```